# issues with nesting elements

Tags: html, sass

I am very new to Sass and I am having issues with the following syntax.

My html

```
<a href="#element">Click here</a>
<div id="element"></div> //corrected div syntax
```

My Sass

```
body
  background-color: yellow
#element
  width: 200px
  height: 200px
  background-color: white

#element
  &:target
    background-color: black
    body
      background-color: green
```

My goal here is that when the `click here` is clicked I want the div background to be black and the body `background color` to be `green`. The div `background` has turned to `black` however the body `background-color` has not changed. Can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sass, nested rules can only apply to children of the outer element. Just like standard CSS, we cannot style parents based on their children.

Your HTML needs to look something like:

```
<body id="element">
    <a href="#element">Click here</a>
    <a href="#target_this_one">Click here</a>
    <div id="subelement"></div>
</body>
```

And then in Sass:

```
body:target 
    background-color: green
    & #subelement 
        background-color: black
```

Or SCSS:

```
:target {
    background-color:green;
    &#subelement {
        background-color:black;
    }
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMbXBv)

Comment: I am not sure but I don't think I can use braces with Sass. It is giving me error

Comment: Invalid CSS after "": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "{"

Comment: Edited to add the [old Sass syntax](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html) ;) ^

Comment: that seems to be working but one thing I did not understand is how did you link the `a href` element with the `body` `background color`

Comment: The way how `click here` and the `body` `background color` are connected is not clear to me

Comment: All the `<a href="#element">` does is point the browser to `yoursite.com/#element`. The `:target` selector gets whichever element in the page has an `id` matching the part of the URL after the `#` - this is called the URL [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). Because, in this case, we have `<body id="#element">`, the `body` element matches `:target`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target). Make sense?

Comment: That defiantly sounds good. But what if I have more than one a href element. Is there a way to make the body background change only based on a particular id?

Comment: I am gonna edit your code so that you can see what I am taking about.

Comment: what if I need to use the a herf with the id target_this_one to the change. How can I go about it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149879/discussion-between-alexander-gottlieb-and-ava-lucas).